# How to create 2 versions of an Odata / EF webservice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an Odata service using the EF provider. I works fine and was easy to create. But now it needs to change. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116804/how-can-i-setup-odata-and-ef-with-out-coupling-to-my-database-structure). But I am not clear on the answer.

I need to be able to serve two (or more) versions of the service concurrently because it is impossible to update all clients at once. I would like to continue using EF code first (because it was so easy until now) but this is not a requirement. I have only few services so I don't mind a rewrite if that will give me the required flexiblity.

What is the best (most easy and maintainable) way to implement an Odata service using c# that can support multiple versions of the same service concurently, from the same db.

I tried using the reflection provider to transform the EF dbcontext. I wanted someting like this:

```
db -> EF db context -> reflection DB context.v1 -> DataService.v1
```

and

```
db -> EF db context -> reflection DB context.v2 -> DataService.v2
```

And I almost got it to work (for reads at least), if only EF selects would permit `ToList()`

I do need to support write as wel (for some services)

Having 2 EF db context targeting the same db would be an acceptable solution but I don't know if and how I can accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I Tried solving the problem by creating a seperate DbContext for each service and mapping it with the fluent API. This almost worked... It seams impossible to have several DbContexts using POCO classes with the same name (but a different namespace (like ..Service.v0.Customer and ..Service.V1.Customer. It all compiles but at runtime an error occurs stating two versions of Customer are present. It is described as a bug in 2010. It is still here so I assume it is expected behaviour by now?

Answer (score 0):

I have found A solution for my problem, and I would like to share it. For a lengthy description of my soltution look [at this blog post](http://blog4rdbr.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/how-to-create-2-versions-of-an-ef-odata-service/).

My solution is bases on three projects:

- a website project, containing "the" ef dbcontexts that maps to my database an provides data to my site and helps migrating the database. In this project I have dataservice.svc class for each version of my service.
- a serviceV1 class library project containing another EF dbcontext that maps between the current db and the dto's of this service version. The mapping (adjustments) are done using the fluent API directly in the datacontext
- a serviceV2 class library project containing another EF dbcontext that maps between the current db and the dto's of this service version.

The datacontext in the service project is set to not migrate the database and ignore schema differences using the following statement:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ServiceV1.MyDbContext>(null);
```

Hope this helps anybody!